# Exclude some views from middleware Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor

I have created the Vapor project. I have registered two views and two API's as like below.

```
    drop.get { req in
        return try drop.view.make("index.html")
    }

    drop.get("home") { req in
        return try drop.view.make("home.html")
    }

    // Register the GET request routes
    drop.get("appname") { request in
        return "Welcome to Swift Web service";
    }

    drop.get("appversion") { request in
        return "v1.0";
    }
```

Middleware code:

```
    // Added the Middleware version for request and response
    final class VersionMiddleware: Middleware {

        // Interact with request and response
        func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> Response {

            //Middleware is the perfect place to catch errors thrown from anywhere in the application.
            do {
                // Exclude the views from middleware
                if ( request.uri.path != "/") {
                    // The request has a 'Version' named token that equals "API \(httpVersion)"
                    guard request.headers["access_token"] == "\(publicAPIKey)" else {
                        throw Abort.custom(
                            status: .badRequest,
                            message: "Sorry, Wrong web service authendication!!"
                        ) // The request will be aborted.
                    }

                }
                let response = try next.respond(to: request)
                response.headers["Version"] = "API \(httpVersion)"
                return response
            } catch {
                throw Abort.custom(
                    status: .badRequest,
                    message: "Sorry, we were unable to query the Web service."
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Added the middleware Configuration:

```
    // Configure the middleware
    drop.addConfigurable(middleware: VersionMiddleware() as Middleware, name: "VersionMiddleware")
```

> My Questions are:
>
> Whenever user try to load home.html it should validate Middleware
>   conditions and if we load index.html server will exclude the
>   middleware validation.
>
> Same as in API's:  Whenever user try to load "/appname" it should
>   validate Middleware conditions and if we load "appversion" server will
>   exclude the middleware validation.

I have done this using request.uri.path != "/". Do we have any another way to configure this in Vapor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group` a set of routes and assign the middleware there

```
drop.group(VersionMiddleware()) { group in
    drop.get("home") { req in
        return try drop.view.make("home.html")
    }

    // Register the GET request routes
    drop.get("appname") { request in
        return "Welcome to Swift Web service";
    }
}

drop.get { req in
    return try drop.view.make("index.html")
}

drop.get("appversion") { request in
    return "v1.0";
}
```

And do not call the `addConfigurable` method

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar you should accept this answer as correct.